# how to override the files in docker container

Tags: docker

I have below dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.7.0
ARG JS_FILE
ENV JS_FILE=${JS_FILE:-"./sum.js"}

ARG JS_TEST_FILE
ENV JS_TEST_FILE=${JS_TEST_FILE:-"./sum.test.js"}

WORKDIR /app
# Copy the package.json to /app
COPY ["package.json", "./"]

# Copy source code into the image
COPY ${JS_FILE} .
COPY ${JS_TEST_FILE} .

# Install dependencies (if any) in package.json
RUN npm install
CMD ["sh", "-c", "tail -f /dev/null"]
```

after building the docker image, if I tried to run the image with the below command, then still could not see the updated files.

```
docker run --env JS_FILE="./Scripts/updated_sum.js" --env JS_TEST_FILE="./Test/updated_sum.test.js" -it <image-name>
```

I would like to see `updated_sum.js` and `updated_sum.test.js` in my container, however, I still see `sum.js` and `sum.test.js`.
Is it possible to achieve this?

This is my current folder/file structure:

```
.
-->Dockerfile
-->package.json
-->sum.js
-->sum.test.js
-->Test
-->--->updated_sum.test.js
-->Scripts
-->--->updated_sum.js
```

Comment: Have you tried to look at docker volumes?

Comment: If you want to use certain build args, you need to pass them in when you build the image. Environment variables passed in when you run are only visible inside the container once it's up and running.

Comment: The only line that runs is CMD when you run the docker. You can write a script that excute the copy of files according to your  env and the tail command. In the CMD run the script

Comment: You are pretty far away from understanding this and an answer here would mean teaching you a lot about docker. I'd recommend going back to reading about the difference between building images and running containers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a deep misunderstanding of how docker works and a tutorial is needed to explain the concepts the OP is missing.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I think it's a pretty big assumption. I know very well docker and may be you are unaware of the question or what I want to achieve.

Comment: @change198, or, I could be a docker captain and a kubernetes/devops trainer with about 40-years experience who can see that you don't know docker very well and can see the mistakes you're making and who is trying to give you helpful advice.

Comment: I agree every phase is learning doesn't matter with your experience but @SoftwareEngineer I don't see your helpful advice. I will be seriously apologetic if I missed out on your advice which is other than closing/reading. So I'm closing this further argument other than focusing on the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using Docker generally involves two phases.  First, you compile your application into an *image*, and then you run a *container* based on that image.  With the plain Docker CLI, these correspond to the `docker build` and `docker run` steps.  `docker build` does everything in the Dockerfile, then stops; `docker run` starts from the fixed result of that and runs the image's `CMD`.

So if you run

```sh
docker build -t sum .
```

The `sum:latest` image will have the `sum.js` and `sum.test.js` files, because that's what the Dockerfile `COPY`s in.  You can then

```sh
docker run --rm sum \
  ls
docker run --rm sum \
  node ./sum.js
```

to see and run the contents of the image.  (Specifying the latter command as `CMD` would be a better practice.)  You can run the command with different environment variables, but it won't change the files in the image:

```sh
docker run --rm -e JS_FILE=missing.js sum ls
# still only has sum.js
docker run --rm -e JS_FILE=missing.js node missing.js
# not found
```

Instead you need to rebuild the image, using `docker build --build-arg` options to provide the values

```sh
docker build \
  --build-arg JS_FILE=./product.js \
  --build-arg JS_TEST_FILE=./product.test.js \
  -t product \
  .
docker run --rm product node ./product.js
```

The extremely parametrizable Dockerfile you show here can be a little harder to work with than a single-purpose Dockerfile.  I might create a separate Dockerfile per application:

```sh
# Dockerfile.sum
FROM node:16.7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY sum.js sum.test.js .
CMD node ./sum.js
```

Another option is to `COPY` the entire source tree into the image (Javascript files are pretty small compared to a complete Node installation) and use a `docker run` command to pick which script to run.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I know the COPY copied the files. But I would like to override those copied files during the run time. One way you can do is to mount or write a script. But I was thinking if you don't give any arguments during the build which means copy the default file and since these arguments are also ENV so I thought you could change the env during the run time. My apologies if this is not clear in the current questions.

Comment: The other files aren't built into the image; setting a `docker run -e` environment variable won't cause the image to be rebuilt.  Just running `node other-script.js` without Docker might be a more straightforward approach here.